# Maximum number of corners that cornerSubPix() can detect

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have to use a large chessboard to calibrate my camera.
I was using `cornerSubPix()` but I do not know and can't found the maximum number of corners that OpernCV functions can detect and support.
In fact, I want to know what is the biggest chessboard size to calibrate camera instead of regular 8x8 one.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for [cornerSubPix](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/ef91d7e8830c36785f0b6fdbf2045da48413dd76/modules/imgproc/src/cornersubpix.cpp) we can see that it iterates up to `count` which is declared as `int`.
This means you can handle `MAX_INT` corners, where `MAX_INT` is the highest number an `int` can represent.

Practically, you will never have a calibration pattern where this is a limiting factor.